# local variable declared in the function is not working

Tags: c, xcode, function, firebird

I have  Query.c, Query.h and main.c files in the project. I defined a SQLOpen()function in Query.c and calling it in the main. The variables required for the execution of function are declared locally. The program is not executing when I call the SQLOpen(0 function in main because it is not detecting one local variable 'char logInData [256];' defined in the SQLOpen()function.

**Query.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ibase.h"
#include "Query.h"

#define DATABASE_PATH "/Users/Sumanth/Desktop/NewDB2.fdb"
int SQLOpen()
{
    ISC_STATUS          status_vector[20];
    isc_db_handle       database=NULL;//database = SQLGetDatabase();
    char                logInData [256];
    short               bufferLength;

    sprintf(logInData, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%s%c%c%s",      isc_dpb_version1,
                                                    isc_dpb_num_buffers,
                                                    1,
                                                    90,
                                                    isc_dpb_user_name,
                                                    strlen("SYSDBA"),
                                                    "SYSDBA",
                                                    isc_dpb_password,
                                                    strlen("masterkey"),
                                                    "masterkey");

    bufferLength = strlen(logInData);
    if (isc_attach_database(status_vector, strlen(DATABASE_PATH), DATABASE_PATH, &database,bufferLength, logInData))
    {

        isc_print_status(status_vector);

    }
    isc_print_status(status_vector);
    //    SQLTestForErrors(status_vector);
    //        throw(ConnectionError, "");
    return 0;

}
```

}
**Query.h**:

```
#ifndef SQLQueryTest_Query_h
#define SQLQueryTest_Query_h

int SQLOpen();

#endif
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Query.h"
#include "/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ibase.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    SQLOpen();

}
```

If I execute this main function, I am getting errors ( The function call is for database function using firebird but it is not connecting)
If I include 'char logInData [256];' in the main function then it is working (connecting to the database). The code is mentioned below.
**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Query.h"
#include "/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ibase.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char logInData [256];
    SQLOpen();

}
```

why I should include 'char logInData [256];' in the main though it is already declared in the SQLOpen() function as a local variable?
 Why it is not reading from the SQLOpen() function?

Kindly look at this issue and help me in solving.

```
It is not displaying any error but I am unable to connect to database. 
The status of status vector is :
ISC_STATUS [20]     
[0] long    0
[1] long    0
[2] long    -1073741909
[3] long    -1073743396 
[4] long    -1881089127 
[5] long    -1881089079 
[6] long    -1073741909 
[7] long    -1880974640 
[8] long    515730401
[9] long    1
[10]    long    -1073743404 
[11]    long    4180
[12]    long    -1073743544 
[13]    long    -1881140636 
[14]    long    4096
[15]    long    0
[16]    long    1
[17]    long    -1073743488 
[18]    long    -1073743480 
[19]    long    -1073743404
for a successful connection to the database,  the status of status vector should look like:
status_vector   ISC_STATUS [20]     
[0] long    1
[1] long    0
[2] long    0
[3] long    0
[4] long    0
[5] long    0
[6] long    0
[7] long    0
[8] long    0
[9] long    0
[10]    long    0
[11]    long    0
[12]    long    0
[13]    long    0
[14]    long    0
[15]    long    0
[16]    long    0
[17]    long    0
[18]    long    0
[19]    long    0
```

Comment: I'm just tossing this out, but almost nothing in your `sprint` is actually a *character*, so why are you using `%c` for the format specifier? It isn't some universal black box of magic. Read how [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) *works*.

Comment: Do you have a makefile ? are you using some IDE ? if the problem is in compiling, please show how you are compiling it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It is not displaying any error but unable to connect to the database. The status of status vector is posted above. Please look at it

Answer (score 0):

When I declare 'ISC_STATUS status_vector[20];' as a global variable, It is working fine and I am able to connect to the database.